# How do I use a form to assign variables and carry out a function on submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller, watir

I asked a similar question yesterday, but it's getting no attention. Here's a similar problem in a different scenario I am currently working with.

Take this function:

```
def facebooklogin (email, password)
  require 'watir-webdriver'

  b = Watir::Browser.new :ff

  b.goto "facebook.com"


  b.text_field(:name => 'email').set "#{email}"
  b.text_field(:name => 'pass').set "#{password}"

  b.button(value: 'Log In').click
end


facebooklogin 'drichards2013@gmail.com', 'notthatstupid'
```

I would like to create a form that has an input for username and password, and a submit button that runs the method when clicked.

I know how to create forms, but I don't know how to link the fields and the submit button to the function.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to use a controller action to execute a Facebook login, your code/approach is somewhat hard to understand - what happens after the action runs and the corresponding view needs to be generated? Or are you trying to just test a local Ruby script?

Comment: Right now I'm just testing a local script, but once the login occurs, I suppose for testing purposes I can redirect the user to their Facebook wall.

Comment: If the form existed, you could automate value entry with watir, but creating the form isn't something you would use watir for.